# Use Config in config file

Tags: laravel

It is possible to reference another Config variable within a configuration files?

Something like this config/app.php

```
'user' => Config::get('mail.user'),
```

Comment: you can define that value in .env file and reference it whenever you want

Comment: Great question! As far as I know, you can't. But I'll be glad to see answer it that ability exists.

Answer (score 4):

No, as far as I know this isn't possible in the way you suggested. As mentioned in the other answers, you should do that by using your environment (like `.env` file).

I suggest you do this in a service provider (like `AppServiceProvider.php`). To me it sounds like you're doing something what isn't actually not a configuration thing. I think you better can do it this way:

As you can see in the documentation of [the configuration repository](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Config/Repository.html#method_set) there is a "set" method on the config repository. So do it like this in a service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
   Config::set('app.user',Config::get('mail.user'));
}
```

Put this in the boot method so every binding is present in the IoC container.

Comment: +1 **But** just because something "`isn't possible`" in Laravel (without provider or .env), does **not** mean that it's "actually not a configuration thing" - In fact, the whole programming concept is just a bunch of different configurations that tell the computer how to work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 4 possible to set variables from other config file, but you need to use:

```
 'url' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::get('constants.url'),
```

instead of:

```
 'url' => Config::get('constants.url'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `mail.php` file in your app/config directory:

```
<?php

    return array(
        'user' => 'username'
    );
```

And then get the value like you proposed:

```
'user' => Config::get('mail.user'),
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's probably not considered best practice, I see no reason not to reference another config if it's a dependency.

One solution I've seen used in projects is to simply `include()` another config file directly. Example:

```php
<?php

// in config/app.php - we've configured the app name:

return [
    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Awesome Site'),
];
```

```php
<?php

// in our custom config/html.php - we'll use the configured
// app name above to build our website's <title> value

// first include the app config
$appConfig = include(config_path('app.php'));

return [
    // now we can utilize $appConfig like an array, because it is one!
    // Note: whatever is return'd from a file is what include() returns
    // ...the PHP manual for the include() function explains this behavior
    // search php.net/manual/en/function.include.php for "Handling Returns"

    'title' => $appConfig['name'] . ' - The Best Website in Existence',

    // or I prefer data_get() which is safer than direct array key access
    // and sort of acts like config() in that it lets us define a default:
    'title' => data_get(
        $appConfig,
        'name',
        'A Pretty OK Site - One of the Most Decent Websites on the Planet'
    ),
];
```

Now we can call `config('html.title')` anywhere in our app and we'll have our site title that utilized the configured app name.

header.blade.php:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ config('html.title') }}</title>
...
```

*A small caveat: we need to watch out for circular dependencies. If we `include('config/html.php')` in `config/app.php` we'll cause an infinite loop!*

A cool thing about this is you're not double loading `app.php` into the app config or anything, you're just using the file in another place. So there's no need to worry about Laravel repeatedly loading `app.php` or anything.

This maybe isn't the "cleanest" or most "proper" solution, but it's super simple, and I think it's a reasonable approach for the times you need it.